# Sort results by expiration date with expired at the end

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am working with Mysql and PHP. I need to sort the results according to the expiration date. The not expired results first, in ascending order and the expired in descending order at the end.

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `promos` ORDER BY `expire_date` ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

For example, considering these values:

```
ID  expire_date
1   2020-05-07 03:30:00
2   2020-05-03 17:00:00
3   2020-04-28 23:30:00
4   2020-05-12 09:00:00
5   2020-03-29 12:00:00
6   2020-04-17 15:00:00
```

I need to get the following order:

```
ID  expire_date
2   2020-05-03 17:00:00  / ASC
1   2020-05-07 03:30:00  / ASC
4   2020-05-12 09:00:00  / ASC
3   2020-04-28 23:30:00  / DESC EXPIRED
6   2020-04-17 15:00:00  / DESC EXPIRED
5   2020-03-29 12:00:00  / DESC EXPIRED
```

How can I achieve this efficiently using MySQL and PHP?

Comment: "but now I need expired promotions to show at the end" you will need to be more specific. Also show the other things you've tried so we have better context for your questoin.

Comment: @JordanS Yes, I have thought about it, but everything I have tried had no results. And that's it, sort by expiration date, but show expired ones at the end ...

Comment: could you give a example with some values for your table ? the result that you have and result that you desire...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a conditional expression to your `ORDER BY` that returns 1 when the `expire_date` has passed and `0` otherwise; that will cause the expired values to sort at the end:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `promos` 
ORDER BY `expire_date` < CURDATE(), `expire_date` ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

To sort expired dates *descending* you need to first sort by `expire_date` ascending if not expired, and then by `expire_date` descending:

```
SELECT *
FROM `promos` 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `expire_date` >= CURDATE() THEN `expire_date`
              ELSE '9999-99-99' 
         END ASC,
         `expire_date` DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/33KuPEjaBzvEvZyaHNfDsU/0)

Comment: Ahh, I had tried it backwards and it didn't work! ... Now, is it possible to order the ones that expired, in descending order? (keeping the current ones in ascending order)

Comment: @Manuel23 see my edit. That should do what you want.